# Google map not show in Bottom Navigation Activity fragment (kotlin)

Tags: android, google-maps

I see only grey, empty, blank window with google logo

1. Activity fragment_map

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <fragment
           android:id="@+id/map"
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   ```
2. MapFragment class

   ```
   class MapFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback{

   private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
   ```

In onCreateView

```
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    var rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)

    var mapFragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)

    return rootView
```

And more code

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
}
```

3. SDK Enabled, API key added and SHA1 configured in Google APIs
4. AndroidManifest

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
       package="com.domain.name">

       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

       <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

       <application
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
           android:supportsRtl="true"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

           <meta-data
               android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

           <meta-data
               android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key"/>

           <activity
               android:name=".MainActivity"
               android:label="@string/app_name">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
           </activity>
       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```
5. In Strings.xml

   ```
       <string name="google_maps_api_key">AIz....2Y</string>
   ```

In Google Map Activity project/application map created key is work normal

Comment: Did you add `GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY` in your Manifest?

Comment: Yes, it exist, i update question

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **API key** in `AndroidManifest.xml` to enable the necessary APIs

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="PASTE-YOUR-API-KEY-HERE" />
```

[Check this](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?_ga=2.111835780.1053331507.1573021104-151397881.1563948318#get-started) to get **API KEY**

Comment: Yes it used, i update question, and also use https://console.developers.google.com/ to create key

Comment: Please add your full `Manifest.xml` to investigate

Comment: Question updated. Can you repeat by creating new Bottom Navigation Activity project and add fragment for map?

Comment: Check your API_KEY. Probably its not correct. I have tried in sample project and it works

Comment: I just create new android kotlin project and it also work in fragment. Now i do it in windows, Will continue investigate

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, i find solution

Answer (score 0):

Remove in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<dist:module dist:instant="true" />
```